# clique 2 nodes stuck mining after outage for one of them

Tags: go-ethereum

i have setup a network of 3 nodes, with 2 of them being sealers (clique) and a third one acting as a proxy.

I know there should be an odd number of nodes to avoid split brain scenarios, but the goal was to freeze the work if either of them was offline and to provide read only access (Write queued) from the third node meanwhile.

The problem is that after a power outage for one of the nodes - both sealers are saying 'Signed recently, must wait for others' and no blocks are mined further.

How can i overcome the situation and keep the network running?

Comment: Probably during the power outage the database got broken and the node was sitting few hundreds block behind. After re-init it synchronized and both started mining.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this one?

Comment: There were no answers, because i have fixed the problem the next day by re-initializing the database ... see my comment above.